# how to add a PHP page link to my footer in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, footer

I have created a custom PHP page name privicy pollicy with name privacy.php.
How would i link the page in footer so that when some1 click on privacy link the page open.
I have call the header and footer in this page.
How to do this.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `wp-content/themes/<your_theme>` directory for your WordPress install, there should be a file called `footer.php`. This is the file that generates your footer output.

To edit this file, open your WordPress dashboard and click on the `Appearances` tab in the navigation bar. Under "Appearances", there will be a link called `Editor` that will open the theme editor for your current theme. Once in the editor, select `Footer (footer.php)` in the list of templates that appears on the right hand side of the editor.

You can modify the HTML for your footer here, and add a link to your privacy page.

Comment: also, if he's using a paid wp theme, there may even be a widget designated for the footer. If that is the case, then there will be the opportunity for him to edit that widget in wordpress and add the html.
Either way, your method will work no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="privacy.php">Privacy policy</a>
```

Comment: hi, Thanks for ansawr But I also want to show it as like other pages. I am calling sider,header and footer in the page and its giving me this error.Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_sidebar() in ......./privacy.php on line 24

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the link in the footer.php of your wordpress theme. You can edit it using the default [theme editor](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_Files)

Answer (score 0):

That is *completely* dependent upon your theme. If your theme doesn't support editing the footer text, you just have to edit your theme's `footer.php` file and add your information there.

The file is located in a place similar to this:

```
/wordpress/wp-content/themes/<theme>/footer.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Go To Appearance -> Editor -> footer.php and edit it Simple
Well You can do it from cpanel also public_html -> wordpress -> wp content -> themes ->  -> footer.php