# Create A wordpress and call it in footer instead of navagation bar in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, footer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to add a PHP page link to my footer in wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7141086/how-to-add-a-php-page-link-to-my-footer-in-wordpress)

I want to add privacy page to my website. I only want to show its link in footer.
How could i do this. if I add new page from the admin side it is shown in the navigation bar.
but i want to show it only in footer.
The link of the page will be shown in footer when user click on the page open up and show privacy page. 
I want to apply same CSS for the page is of my other page.
I have try and created a custom page locally and have called the function of get-header and get-footer but it doesn't work.
Any body guide me how to do this..

I want the footer have following info and pages
     Copyright ABC 2011 all right reserved. Privacy Policy   Refund Policy 
Again lemme clear i want to show those pages only in footer not any where else.

Comment: It's only been 36 mins... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7141086/how-to-add-a-php-page-link-to-my-footer-in-wordpress

Comment: I just wrote an answer to a question that has a duplicate with another answer. Thanks for wasting my time.